# Control one mosfet with 2 PWM signal sources

Tags: mosfet, pwm, esp8266

Currently I'm facing small issue and I can't find the answer. I've bought one of these Chinese RGB controllers which are using 2.4GHz touch remote control. Surprisingly for me this device is working fine for now but I want to add it to my Home Automation hub using ESP8266. Please check following pictures of the main board:

[image]
[image]

As you can see there are 2 chips - one is the main MCU the other is about the 2.4GHz communication, after that are the 3 mosfets for the LED strip.

My goal is to preserve the current functionality and "just" to add one ESP8266 module for further "improvements". Is it possible? How this can be achieved? I will appreciate any advice/comment. Thanks!

Comment: 1) I doubt that this module is using 2.4 Ghz, I bet it is using 315 or 433 MHz. What is the number on the chip nearest to the "antenna" (that piece of wire sticking out). 2) ESP8266 is a WiFi module, if this module is not using Wifi (and I bet it does not) you cannot connect it to the ESP8266. Because some module uses 2.4 GHz and another also uses 2.4 GHz does not mean they can communicate. Example: Wifi, Bluetooth, SigBee, all 2.4 GHz but cannot communicate to eachother.

Comment: *This is my first post so please bear with me!* Next time instead of making excuses beforehand, read the rules about what is allowed and what not: Top right: Help => Tour

Comment: @FakeMoustache Thanks for your comment! I know that usage of the same frequency will not **allow** them to communicate directly! My idea is to add ESP8266 on top of this and use 3 wires to connect the mosfets to the ESP directly, but in this case the PWM signal from the existing MCU will interfere with the ESP. That is the reason why I need advice what is possible and what is not. And about the label of the RF chip - yesterday I was unable to read it - maybe the manufacturer try to remove it. I will try again later today. FakeMoustache note taken -> post edited!

Comment: *My idea is to add ESP8266 on top of this and use 3 wires to connect the mosfets to the ESP directly* That was not clear from your question. You cannot just connect to the MOSFETs directly as there are also the outputs of the uC on the board still connected. You would have 3 times 2 outputs fighting over the MOSFET so that is a no-go. You could solve this using some logic but I think that is beyond your knowledge.

Comment: If this module uses 315 or 433 MHz (check your remote !) you could get  a 315 or 433 MHz transmitter module, connect that to the ESP8266 and make it send the same commands as your remote. You'd have to reverse engineer those remote codes though, you could do that with a 315 or 433 MHz receiver and an Arduino. See how this is getting a bit complicated already ?

Comment: @FakeMoustache, I'm not a person who is being scared of complicated things - my work is related to complicated enough tasks. I know that my idea have it's own issues and can't work out of the box. Thanks for your advice I will try to get the IC labels from the main controller because all chips on the remote are totally without any labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a scenario like this:

1. Cut the traces to the MOSFET's gates.
2. Attach those three signals from the on-board MCU to suitable (interrupt, input-capture, etc) inputs on your extra MCU
3. Attach PWM outputs from your extra MCU to the gates of the MOSFETs.

You can then make a decision (using what criteria is entirely up to you) as to whether you output your own PWM or the captured PWM to the MOSFETs. The latter could either be by capturing and calculating the duty cycle of the incoming PWM and replicating it with your own PWM (that would be the nicest, since you could fade smoothly between your custom setting and the default setting, for instance), or by direct mirroring of the input to the output.

Since the MOSFETs are simple open-collector sinks it would even be possible to do it without any modification of the existing board, assuming you have more suitable MOSFETs you can add to the system:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGjzSP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

An alternative would be to place a MUX in place of the MCU and switch between the two PWM outputs:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyqdT1.png)</sup>

That method is easier to program for (no need to capture incoming PWM), but requires extra components (the MUX).